# How does this string alignment works?

Tags: python, string, format, f-string

I am trying to solve a problem in string formatting.I came across an approach like the following.

```
print('{0:<{1}}'.format('vamsi',10))
```

This will left align the string 'vamsi' by filling all spaces wherever necessary to meet the length of 10.
Also, How to use some arbitrary characters like * rather spaces while aligning in such an approach?
Anyhow,
I tried to replicate the same in f strings.

```
name = 'vamsi'
print(f'{name}:<{10}',end='|')
```

(I have purposefully used '|' character to have a check on final length of the string.)
Please someone help me understand how this works.

Comment: https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/, https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax

Answer (score 1):

Specify the filling character like so:

```
{0:*<{1}}
```